# copyItemAtPath:toPath:error: is returning NO

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsurl, nsfilemanager, file-copying

The chapter I'm reading is talking about `NSFileManager`, and the author said to create an empty file called `testFile`. The `testFile` is under the same folder as `main.m`. I didn't create `newfile`. I'm not able to copy `testFile`, and it's `returning 2` and a `NSLog` saying `@"couldnt copy file"`. I tried to put the argument for toPath: as `@"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/newfile"`

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *fName = @"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/testFile";
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath: fName] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"couldnt find file");
            return 1;
        }

        if ([fm copyItemAtPath:fName toPath:@"newfile" error:NULL] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"couldnt copy file");
            return 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second path must be also absolute.

```
[fm copyItemAtPath: @"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/testFile" toPath: @"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/newFile" error: NULL];
```

Note: You should use the `NSURL`-based methods instead of the `NSString`-based ones.

Comment: Sorry, `[fm copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/testFile" toPath:@"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/newfile" error:NULL]` didn't work do you have any other suggestions? Oh I'm just following what the author is instructing. Maybe he'll go over `NSURL` later.

Comment: @Emily Are you absolutely sure this path exists and that you have permission to write in it? I don't know why it would fail otherwise. What if you try the URL variant: `[fm copyItemAtURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/testFile"] toURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/Users/el/Desktop/prog/prog/newFile"] error: nil]`?

Comment: @Emily What you also could do too is actually request the error info, like so: `NSError *error = nil; [fm copyItemAtURL: (…) toURL: (…) error: &error]; if (error) NSLog(error);`

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry. It turns out the file was copied, but it was hidden. *embarrassed* Thanks so much for the help!